# Expectation of sum of distribution functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove the next:

If $X,Y$ are random variables with distribution functions $F$ and $G$ which have no common discontinuities, then $$E(F(X))+E(G(Y))=1.$$ Interpret the sum of expectation on the left as a probability.

I am stuck in the proof of this; I've proved that $E(F(X))=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\displaystyle\sum_{a}P^2(X=a)\right)$ where the sum runs over the atoms of $F.$

I was trying to use the above but clearly there are terms with sums run over atoms of $F$ and $G,$ which intuitively must be zero because there are no common discontinuities.

Also I was trying to use Fubini but I'm not sure how to tilizing it:

$$E(F(X))+E(G(Y))=E(F(X)+G(Y))=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}(F(x)+G(y)dH(x,y))$$ where $H$ is the distribution function of random vector $(X,Y).$

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: Do you have any doubt in the solution I presented?

Answer (score 2):

We first figure out the distribution function of $Z = F(X)$.

$$F_{Z}(z) = P(Z \le z) = P(F(X) \le z), \quad 0 \le z \le 1$$
$$=P(X \le F^{-1} (z))$$
$$=F(F^{-1}(z))$$
$$= z$$

Therefore $Z$ follows $U(0,1)$ distribution. Can you take it from here?

Edit: We assume here that the inverse of the distribution function exists. This can be ensured if the distribution function is strictly increasing.

Comment: Thanks to answer @Vizag. How can we ensure there exists inverse of F? Or is the generalized inverse?

Comment: Refer: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Inverse_distribution_function_(quantile_function)

Comment: It's a good question, we can ensure that inverse exists if the distribution function is strictly increasing.

Comment: Exactly; such distributions must be considering in the general case.

Comment: Yeah. I have added a line or two in the answer as well talking about this point.